# Gamma distribution and scaled gamma distribution

Tags: statistics

Suppose $W\sim gamma(p; \theta)$, for $\frac{EW^{1/2}}{EW^{-1/2}}=3$, and $\frac{EW^{3/2}}{EW^{1/2}}=5$, determine the pair $(p; \theta)$

What I tried:

$$\frac{EW^{1/2}}{EW^{-1/2}}=\frac{\theta^{1/2}\Gamma(P+1/2)}{\theta^{-1/2}\Gamma(P-1/2)}=\theta p= 3$$$$\frac{EW^{1/2}}{EW^{3/2}}=\frac{\theta^{3/2}\Gamma(P+3/2)}{\theta^{1/2}\Gamma(P+1/2)}=\theta p= 5$$

Which is clearly not right, but I don't know where I am wrong, any help, thanks!

Comment: Should be $\theta (p-1/2)=3$ and $\theta(p+1/2)=5$? Then $\theta=2$ and $p=4$.

Comment: @angryavian If you don't mind, could you explain why (−1/2)=3, (+1/2)=5?

Comment: @angryavian never mind, I know where I am wrong, a really stupid question